# Plugin translations not installed but... strings are translated!

Tags: plugin-development, translation, widget-text, textdomain

I've had for a long time a site with the famous [Recent Tweets Widget](https://wordpress.org/plugins/recent-tweets-widget/). The plugin came as part of a theme, and back in the day, it included translation .po and .mo files for French language. I didn't pay attention to this before.

But recently I have found that the strings indicating the tweet's age (x days/months ago, etc.) are translated into Spanish, main language of the site. I have confirmed that **the translated strings are not in the .po files**, neither from the plugin nor from the site translations. So I assume they come fron an external site. I couldn't tell the exact date when it happened.

Digging about this oddity, I've found that translations can now be managed in http://translations.wordpress.org. And in this site, the aforementioned plugin exists, with 8 translations (a specially bad one for Spanish). My guess is somehow WP could be recovering this translation from the site, via REST API or similar. But I can't find any specific call for this in the code.

I wonder if the __() function has now the ability to recover external translations for a given text domain, or, in the shape of a question: **what could be the possible sources for this "ghost" translation?** Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *Recent Tweets Widget* is one of the many plugins which their translations are managed through [translate.wordpress.org](https://translate.wordpress.org/), and this means that upon installing the plugin (*remember, installing and activating are different), WordPress (on your site) will automatically download the plugin's language pack (`.po` and `.mo` files) from translate.wordpress.org, and then store the translation files in the WordPress languages directory which defaults to `wp-content/languages`.

But WordPress will only do that if a core/site language pack is found at `wp-content/languages/<locale>.mo` (see [`get_available_languages()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_available_languages/)), which in your case should be true — e.g. you might find the MO file at `wp-content/languages/es_ES.mo`.

And for plugins, the downloaded language packs are saved to `wp-content/languages/plugins/<locale>.<mo|po>`; so for example, the *Recent Tweets Widget* plugin where the text domain is `recent-tweets-widget`, you'd find the translations for the *Spanish (Spain)* locale (`es_ES`) in:

- `wp-content/languages/plugins/recent-tweets-widget-es_ES.mo`
- `wp-content/languages/plugins/recent-tweets-widget-es_ES.po`

Also, it should be noted that since WordPress 4.6, language pack found in the `wp-content/languages/plugins` directory takes precedence over the one in the plugin's directory — which is normally loaded via `load_plugin_textdomain()` — so with the *Recent Tweets Widget* plugin as an example, if you had both `wp-content/languages/plugins/recent-tweets-widget-es_ES.mo` and `wp-content/plugins/recent-tweets-widget/languages/recent-tweets-widget-es_ES.mo`, the former will *be automatically loaded* and be used instead of the latter.

**Hence, I believe that MO file is the source of that "ghost" translation. :)**

(Well if your site's locale is `es_ES`, but even if not, try looking for one of the other Spanish locales. Then try renaming the file, e.g. `<locale>.mo.bak`, and see if the "ghost" translation persists.)

Last but not least, when a plugin is **deleted** (and not simply deactivated), WordPress will also remove the plugin translation files in the `wp-content/languages/plugins`, *so keep that in mind* if you wish to edit those files/translations.

**Further Reading**

- https://wordpress.org/support/wordpress-version/version-4-6/#highlights
- [Translator’s Handbook » Plugin/Theme Authors Guide](https://make.wordpress.org/polyglots/handbook/plugin-theme-authors-guide/)
- [Plugin Author – Quick Reference Guide](https://wp-info.org/pa-qrg/) (on WP Info)

Comment: PS: Sorry, the last two `<locale>` should be `<text domain>`.. I'll correct that later :)

Comment: Thanks, exactly what I was looking for, but couldn't find in Google, nor in WordPress search. Thank you very much.